# Can someone explain what Japanese law says about my medication?

Tags: criminal-law, medical, japan

I have a mild form of autism. To treat this I take one 60mg pill of Biphentin every day. Biphentin is "Methylphenidate Hydrochloride", being in the same category as drugs like Ritalin and other methylphenidates.

Knowing the above, and that I live in Canada; what about Japanese drug law would I have to understand and obey if I wanted to visit the country without being arrested for possession?

How much can I bring? How long can I stay with it? What can the police ask of me? If I must disclose information to authorities, what must I disclose and how? Do I need any kind of paperwork? And if so, who would need to see it?

Japan's drug laws are notoriously strict, showing zero-tolerance, with almost zero exceptions, especially for tourists; with up to date information being vary scarcely available; thus, I want to be quite careful and thus, understandably, I ask.

Sorry if this is more for USA or EU law; but I hope ya'll can help me! :)

Comment: Did you ask the Japanese Embassy in Canada? http://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa.html They will give you the definitive answer.

Comment: Oh ya, I guess... thx m8! :D

Comment: As he said; plus http://www.au.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_medicine_en.html – you may need to get permission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best thing to do is contact the Japanese Embassy in Canada; they can give you definitive, up to date advice, and possibly provide you with docs to take with you. Try [Visa and Travel Information : Embassy of Japan in Canada](http://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa.html)